# Correct apache server configuration to deploy Angular2 + Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, angular, apache, .htaccess

I build a template for my wordpress site using angular2, and the WP-REST API, Right now I have a working version ([link](http://bellaterra.ireevo.net/)) but I have a problem. When I open the page on a custom route (not the home) server give 404 error, but using the router links works as I want.
to clarify:

- open: [home page](http://bellaterra.ireevo.net/) and navigate in the page all OK!
- open: [direct link to custom route](http://bellaterra.ireevo.net/contacto) and give 404 error

my `.htacces` file is the default for Wordpress

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and i'm using the /%postname%/ permalink cfg on my wp backend

Answer (score 0):

Check your database > wp_options

`option_name` **siteurl** & **home**

`option_value` **http://bellaterra.ireevo.net**

Comment: this values are ok!